# Cant create or update tables on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubymine

I can't force it to go to the update method and to the destroy method, it gives the error " ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/tourbases/1"): "when deleting and" ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/tourbases/1/edit"): "when updating
Here my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'pages#index'



resources :tourbases, only: %i[index new edit create update destroy]
resources :countries, only: %i[index new edit create update destroy]
resources :regions, only: %i[index new edit create update destroy]
resources :cities, only: %i[index new edit create update destroy]
```

This my buttons:

```
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href=<%=edit_tourbasis_path(tour) %>>Change</a>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', tourbasis_path(tour), method: :delete, :class => "btn btn-outline-secondary"  %>
```

end

Comment: should i add  inflect.singular "tourbases", "tourbase" to somewhere ?

Comment: The first link should fire a GET, why is it a POST? it could be that the url itself is correct but the http verb is making it fail. Can you remove type=button from the link?

Comment: does not help((

Comment: Would you mind running `rake routes` in your terminal and show us the results?

Comment: http verb is definitely the issue here. Update should be PATCH or PUT to `/tourbases/1`, destroy should be DELETE to `/tourbases/1`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dc8oJ0D.png

Comment: @SiimLiiser so how can i force it to be patch and delete ? staff like this - put 'tourbases/:id/edit' => 'tourbases#edit'  seems stupid and actually does not work to. what should i do ?

Comment: Are you talking about routes? `resources` in routes takes care of all of it already. You can see from your routes picture that both PUT and PATCH to `/tourbases/1` are there and they route to the correct action (`update`). Edit is meant to render the form to make changes (GET request) and update is to actually make those changes.

Comment: @SiimLiiser if i have already correct routes, there are no ideas to fix the issue

Comment: Your routes are correct, but the requests that are made to the server don't match those routes. How requests are made is wrong, I suggest investigating from there. POST request should not be made for update and delete.

Comment: @SiimLiiser so there are only to links, which can  have influence on it. But i cant imagine what i can change in link(button) like this **<%= link_to 'Delete', tourbasis_path(tour), method: :delete, :class => "btn btn-outline-secondary"  %>**

Comment: is it working on your other resources like countries or regions? `'tourbases'.singularize` are returning `tourbasis` and vice versa so i don't think the inflection is your problem here

Comment: also your problem is on the *update* page, not *edit*. giving us `<a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href=<%=edit_tourbasis_path(tour) %>>Change</a>` is pointless.